# How to avoid invisible breakpoints in QtCreator?

Tags: multithreading, qt, debugging, qt-creator, breakpoints

QtCreator is my favorite C++ IDE. Now I use " QtCreator + VC141 (vs2017) + WinDebug" to develop my x64 software on windows.

It works perfectly at first. But then at a time, it often encounter invisible breakpoints  when I start debugging.
The screen show following picture.

[image]

I use QtCreator in this situation for a long time, but when I finally need to implement software itnerface, I found it is impossible to used QtCreator for debugging. Because UI needs evevent loop, QtCreator always triggered invisible breakpoint.

By the way, I found that QtCreator usually (not every time) encounters invisible breakpoints when threads changes.

Does anyone have encoutered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Under "tools->Options->Debugger"

disable

1. "Breakpoints->Thread creation"
2. "Breakpoints->Thread exit"
3. "Various->When CrtDbgReport() called"

The problem doesnot shown any more.

But debuggers will no stop at "assert()" in code.

So Turn on "1/2", if you need "assert()".